# Output of scala For loop

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop

```
scala> var sum =0
sum: Int = 0

scala> val s = "hello"
s: String = hello

scala> for (i <-0 to s.length-1)
     | sum +=s(i)

scala> println (sum)
532
```

I am new to Scala. Can someone explain why I am getting 532 as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the values (*Unicode codepoints*) of the characters in the string "hello".

To see these values, try this:

```
"hello".map(_.toInt)
```

will result in:

```
Vector(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)
```

These are the values you're adding.

Comment: @user3036391 also, the right way to do this in scala is `"hello".sum.toInt`
Do not use loops and vars, they are evil, and not needed in scala in 99% of cases. Just pretend, they do not exist.